# Noise when talking to printer over serial connection

Tags: python, printing, serial-port, flow-control

When my software is talking to a receipt printer over a serial connection, it is encountering a lot of messages that appear to be meaningless, possibly noise. Can anyone help me identify what is going on? Do I need to respond to this? Can I just ignore it and proceed?

Some configuration info:

my computer:

```
{'baudrate': '9600', 'flowcontrol': 'XON/XOFF', 'port': 'CNCB0'}
Serial<id=0x17ab1b0, open=True>(port='\\\\.\\CNCB0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=0.01, xonxoff=1, rtscts=0, dsrdtr=0), printer: Serial<id=0x17ab290, open=True>(port='\\\\.\\COM1', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='E', stopbits=1, timeout=0.01, xonxoff=1, rtscts=0, dsrdtr=0)
```

printer:

```
{'parity': 'E', 'baudrate': '9600', 'bytesize': '8', 'brand': 'Epson', 'stopbits': '1', 'flowcontrol': 'XON/XOFF', 'interface': 'Serial', 'port': '1'}
```

My computer starts by sending the printer

```
'\x1bv'
```

and then there is a constant loop of my computer sending the printer

```
'\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv\x1bv'
```

and the printer replying with

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 1):

> it is encountering a lot of messages that appear to be meaningless

Receiving total garbage over a serial async line is typically a baud rate issue.

Receiving random garbage over a serial async line is typically a framing issue, such as mismatched parity.

Your computer

> parity='N'

Your printer

> 'parity': 'E'

ERGO you have mismatched parity settings (None versus Even) and frame size (10 bits versus 11 bits).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential causes.  First, can you get *any* good data? Or is it all garbage?  If it's all trash, then a mismatch in baudrate is a common problem. Beyond that, there are several things to check:

1. Verify your comm settings.  You are specifying software flow control. Are you certain this is correct?
2. Verify your cable and/or connection.  Is the cable good? How about the connectors? How long is the cable? Are there any strong noise sources nearby?
3. How are you connecting the printer to your computer?  Is it a true COM port? Or is it one of the USB to RS-232 converter cables? Are you connecting to a laptop or a desktop? Frequently, laptops "fake" RS-232 signals using something like +/- 5V instead of the true +/-12V RS-232 signals.  As a result, the communications can be more susceptible to noise.